# Is it possible to dedicate a monitor for VirtualBox use?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

Configuration

- Windows 7
- Intel i7-based platform
- ATI Raedon HD 5850 Display card
- VirtualBox with Ubuntu 10.10 as guest

Problem:

I wanted to connect another monitor to my current setup (Which is a single monitor, dell U2711 monitor) so that it would be dedicated to one (or more if possible) virtual machine and for virtual machine use only. Ideally, I do not want the Windows desktop to extend to that particular monitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done as Virtual Box is an application that runs within Windows.  You will have to extend the desktop to the other screen.   You can however maximize the Virtual Machine to that screen size and use it solely for the VM.

I have found however that there may be a way that you can "dual-boot" two operating systems as the same time using [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/index.php).  I found [this](http://www.windowswatch.co.uk/2008/02/forget-dual-boo.html) article about it.  I have **not** used this software and do now know how it works, but this *may* be a solution for you.

Comment: And, afaik, you can make the VM fullscreen in that monitor, too.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is it entirely possible to use a monitor that is being detected by windows, but not had desktop extended on it, on windows?

Comment: @bubu not to my knowledge